# color co-occurrence histogram

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I went through the following paper:

http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68706/cvpr1.pdf

which is about color co-occurrence histogram for object recognition. It has the advantage of adding spacial information comparing to the color histograms.

I didnt understand how to effectively implement it.

Does anybody knows where can I get the code for this or some guides to implement it using matlab?

Comment: Why do you want to use color co-occurrence histograms for Object Recognition? Object recognition has significantly advanced since this paper and there are more sophisticated and effective object recognition methods available.

Comment: Do you have some examples of the more sophisticated object recognition methods?

Comment: The co-occurrence histogram method does not require a lot of significant training images.